# Can't boost thumbnail field - SOLR

Tags: java, apache, solr, null, boosting

Solr newbie here

I am constructing queries to boost certain items on my webpage, and I want to be able to boost fields that contain a thumbnail (image) value:

```
<doc>
<str name="campaign"/>campaign
<str name="productclass">B</str>
<str name="thumbnail">
HPMAssets/d120001/derivates/1/250/103/005358625_121203_080900_9853_thumb.jpg
</str>
</doc>
```

For instance in the above, "thumbnail" contains a value and should therefore be displayed higher up on the search result page. I have tried:

```
q=(thumbnail:["" TO *])^99        (all non-empty thumbnails)
q=(-thumbnail:[* TO *])^99       (all non-null thumbnails)
q=(thumbnail:*)^99                (all thumbnails)
```

But it doesn't work. I know for a fact that I can boost values:

```
(campaign:campaign)^99
```

Works and will display articles with 'campaign' (that is to say, items/articles with a special offer) first on the resulting page.

Why doesn't this work for thumbnails? How do I formulate a Solr-query so that it displays articles with an existing thumbnail before articles without an existing thumbnail?

**EDIT**

As MatsLindh correctly pointed out,

q=(-thumbnail:[* TO *])^99

Means all documents without a thumbnail and not all non-null thumbnails, which would be:

q=(thumbnail:[* TO *]).

Comment: Please don't misuse tags -- there's nothing in this question related to [boost](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info).

Comment: Apologies. I meant to use "Boosting", wrote the question a bit too hasty.

Comment: `q=(-thumbnail:[* TO *])^99` means all documents without a thumbnail - `thumbnail:[* TO *]` would be all documents with the field present. Have you tried moving the boost to a separate clause with `bq` and looking at what the output from `debugQuery=true` says?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, having a bq clause, which for some reason did not work. Anywho, I solved the problem by checking my schema.xml and changing the indexed value for thumbnail to true, whereby I re-indexed my whole schema to make the changes apply (see my answer to this post). The bq clause never worked for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that thumbnails were not being indexed in my schema.xml:

```
 <field name="thumbnail" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"  multiValued="false"/>
```

So I changed the "indexed" value to "true" and then re-indexed my whole schema. There was never anything wrong with the query-syntax.

Hope this helps any lost Solr soul in the future.